# Data Migration with Doctrine

Tags: mysql, doctrine, data-migration

I have inherited a proprietary CMS that uses `Doctrine` for the Database Setup, this includes the awful `lft`, `rgt` and level columns.

My issue is migrating data from an old database to this new database, does Doctrine auto create these `lft` and `rgt` fields? I can't figure out how to set the parent, when I do `$node->save();` it creates the record but sets `lft` and `rgt` to NULL.

Anybody have an idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

That table is used in [nested-set](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/hierarchical-data/en#nested-set) model. It might be hard to learn how to work with it, but once you do, you **will** love it.
lft, rgt and level must not be written manually unless you **really** know what you are doing. The best solution would be to read instructions carefully, create some dummy DB and practise nested-set on it.